# How to bring data back from model to controller

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects... for a concrete example, let's call the array `People`, where each `person` has a `uniqueID`, a `name` and a `tagline`.

I'm using the foreach templating to display a list of these people, like so:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in People">
        {{person.name}}: {{person.tagline}}
        ...
```

Simple enough to take the data from the controller and sync it into the model.

Now, I want to click on a person and do something complicated with their information. Like so:

```
<ul ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="person in People" ng-click="clickHandler($event)">
        ...
```

Right now, I have access to the DOM element like this:

```
$scope.clickHandler = function($event) {
    var domElement = $event.currentTarget;
        ...
```

But, how do I get the data from the relevant `person` object (the one that was clicked on), so that I can possibly look at their `uniqueID` (which is not stored in the DOM)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you use ng-repeat you should remember that it creates a new scope. This scope inherits from the parent scope. But for each item in ng-repeat a new scope is created.

In order to access this scope you will also have to introduce a controller which will work along with that scope. So you would have to do

```
 <li ng-repeat="person in People" ng-click="clickHandler($event)" ng-controller="PersonController">
 ...
```

In your javascript

```
function PersonController($scope){
  //In here you will be able to access the person from "person in People"

  $scope.clickHandler = function($event){
    console.log($scope.person);    
  }
}
```

It is this scope that will have the person variable. Now, you could also declare a clickHandler here.

You should note that for each person in People a new scope will be created as well as a new Controller (PersonController ). And in your person controller you will be able to access and manipulate your person to your hearts content.

Comment: Can you help me access the parent scope? Either within the HTML (I want to pass the People scope into the click handler) or within the PersonCtrl (I can ask for PersonCtrl.$scope.parent to get the data?)

Comment: Can you describe your scenario? You should not be accessing parent scope unless its absolutely necessary!

Answer (score 6):

Try defining `$scope.clickHandler` on a parent controller and `ng-click="clickHandler(person)"`, with this you will use the parent scope and don't need to instancie one controller for each row

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `$event` you can pass `person` object directly to function and then you can perform any complex operation there.
e.g

```
 <li ng-repeat="person in People" ng-click="clickHandler(person)">
           Name: {{person.name}}, Tagline: {{person.tagline}},  Id:  {{person.uniqueId}}
  </li>
```

**Working Example:**

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

(function() {
    "use strict";
    myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.People = [{
                "name": "Sam",
                "tagline": "Sam Test",
                "uniqueId": 123

            },
            {
                "name": "Dominik",
                "tagline": "Dominik Test",
                "uniqueId": 100

            },
            {
                "name": "Chris",
                "tagline": "Chris Test",
                "uniqueId": 555

            }
        ];

        $scope.clickHandler = function(person) {
            console.log(person);
            // You can perform any complex operation here as you have access to person here. 
        }
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
   <li ng-repeat="person in People" ng-click="clickHandler(person)">
       Name: {{person.name}}, Tagline: {{person.tagline}},  Id:  {{person.uniqueId}}
     </li>
  </div>
</div>
```